# Android: Json parse in listview

Tags: android, json, listview, android-listview, android-asynctask

Im trying to parse some items in a listview and when I scroll down I want to get more products and add them to the list.
But my code doesnt do that it either refreshes it or crashes.
Any help?
Also adding a footer doesnt work either i get an classcastexception

JSONParser:

```
 package com.lars.json;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.List;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import com.lars.R.drawable;

import android.R;
import android.util.Log;

/** A class to parse json data */
public class JSONParser {

    // Receives a JSONObject and returns a list
    public List<HashMap<String,Object>> parse(JSONObject jObject){      

        JSONArray jProducts = null;
        try {       
            // Retrieves all the elements in the 'countries' array 
            jProducts = jObject.getJSONArray("products");
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

         // Invoking getCountries with the array of json object
         // where each json object represent a country
        return getProducts(jProducts);
    }


    private List<HashMap<String, Object>> getProducts(JSONArray jProducts){
        int productsCount = jProducts.length();
        List<HashMap<String, Object>> productList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,Object>>();
        HashMap<String, Object> product = null; 

        // Taking each country, parses and adds to list object 
        for(int i=0; i<productsCount;i++){
            try {
                // Call getCountry with country JSON object to parse the country 
                product = getJSON((JSONObject)jProducts.get(i));
                productList.add(product);

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }

        return productList;
    }

    // Parsing the Country JSON object 
    private HashMap<String, Object> getJSON(JSONObject f){

        HashMap<String, Object> country = new HashMap<String, Object>();

        String id = "";
        String naam = "";
        String status = "";
        String prijs = "";
        String productnum = "";


        try {
            String priceone = f.getString("prijsex");

            id = f.getString("id");
            naam = f.getString("naam");
            status = f.getString("status");
            prijs = "€" + priceone;
            productnum = f.getString("productnum");


            country.put("id", id);
            country.put("naam", naam);
            country.put("img", com.lars.R.drawable.tlogotrans);
            country.put("prijs", prijs);
            country.put("img_path", "http://www.lars.com/images/" + productnum + ".jpg");

            if(Integer.parseInt(status) > 0){
            country.put("status", com.lars.R.drawable.stock);
            }else{
            country.put("status", com.lars.R.drawable.nostock);
            }


        } catch (JSONException e) {         
            e.printStackTrace();
        }       
        return country;
    }
}
```

Download tasks and Listview loaders:

```
/** A method to download json data from url */
    private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
        String data = "";
        InputStream iStream = null;
        try{
                URL url = new URL(strUrl);

                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url 
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

                // Connecting to url 
                urlConnection.connect();

                // Reading data from url 
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

                BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

                StringBuffer sb  = new StringBuffer();

                String line = "";
                while( ( line = br.readLine())  != null){
                    sb.append(line);
                }

                data = sb.toString();

                br.close();

        }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
        }finally{
                iStream.close();
        }

        return data;
    }



    /** AsyncTask to download json data */
    private class DownloadTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{
        String data = null;




                @Override
                protected String doInBackground(String... url) {

                        try{

                            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);

                        }catch(Exception e){
                            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
                        }
                        return data;
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(String result) {

                        // The parsing of the xml data is done in a non-ui thread 
                        ListViewLoaderTask listViewLoaderTask = new ListViewLoaderTask();
                        Log.i("Result", result);

                        if(result.equals(" ")){
                            Log.i("No img", "No Img");
                        }else{

                                listViewLoaderTask.execute(result);


                        }
                        // Start parsing xml data


                }
    }

    /** AsyncTask to parse json data and load ListView */
    private class ListViewLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, SimpleAdapter>{



        JSONObject jObject;
        private List<HashMap<String, Object>> products;
        // Doing the parsing of xml data in a non-ui thread 
        @Override
        protected SimpleAdapter doInBackground(String... strJson) {
            try{

                jObject = new JSONObject(strJson[0]);
                JSONParser jsonpars = new JSONParser();
                jsonpars.parse(jObject);
            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("JSON Exception1",e.toString());
            }

            // Instantiating json parser class
            JSONParser jsonpars = new JSONParser();

            // A list object to store the parsed countries list


            try{
                // Getting the parsed data as a List construct
                if(set == 0){
                products = jsonpars.parse(jObject);
                }else{
                    products.addAll(jsonpars.parse(jObject));

                }

            }catch(Exception e){
                Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
            }          

            // Keys used in Hashmap 
            String[] from = { "img","naam","status","prijs"};
            // Ids of views in listview_layout
            int[] to = { R.id.imPThumb,R.id.tvPRName,R.id.imstock,R.id.tvPRPrijs};

            // Instantiating an adapter to store each items
            // R.layout.listview_layout defines the layout of each item         
            SimpleAdapter adapter = new SimpleAdapter(getBaseContext(), products, R.layout.productlijstrow, from, to);  

            return adapter;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             publishProgress();
             Log.i("ListView Loader Task", "Update");
            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }

        /** Invoked by the Android on "doInBackground" is executed */
        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(SimpleAdapter adapter) {

            // View v = getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.footerview, null);
            //list.addFooterView(v);
            // Setting adapter for the listview


            list.setAdapter(adapter);



            if(set == 0){
            list.setOnScrollListener(onAnswersScrolled);
            set++;
            }
            list.setOnItemClickListener(onAnswerClicked);

               list.setTextFilterEnabled(true);
           /*    list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
                    HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) lv.getItemAtPosition(position);

                    Bundle extra = new Bundle();
                    Intent i = new Intent("com.lars.productdescription");
                    extra.putString("id", o.get("id"));
                    i.putExtras(extra);
                    startActivity(i);

                    }
                });*/

            for(int i=0;i<adapter.getCount();i++){
                HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(i);
                String imgUrl = (String) hm.get("img_path");
                Log.i("imgurlonPost", imgUrl);
                ImageLoaderTask imageLoaderTask = new ImageLoaderTask();

                HashMap<String, Object> hmDownload = new HashMap<String, Object>();
                hmDownload.put("img_path",imgUrl);

                hmDownload.put("position", i);

                // Starting ImageLoaderTask to download and populate image in the listview 
                imageLoaderTask.execute(hmDownload);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

         /*   list.setOnScrollListener(new OnScrollListener(){



            });*/

        }       
    }

    /** AsyncTask to download and load an image in ListView */
    private class ImageLoaderTask extends AsyncTask<HashMap<String, Object>, Void, HashMap<String, Object>>{

        @Override
        protected HashMap<String, Object> doInBackground(HashMap<String, Object>... hm) {


            InputStream iStream=null;
            String imgUrl = (String) hm[0].get("img_path");
            int position = (Integer) hm[0].get("position");
            HashMap<String, Object> hmBitmap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
            URL url;
            try {
                url = new URL(imgUrl);



                // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
                HttpURLConnection urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
                Log.i("imgUrl", imgUrl);
                // Connecting to url                
                urlConnection.connect();
          //      Log.i("Response", urlConnection.getResponseMessage());
                // Reading data from url 

                if(urlConnection.getResponseMessage().contains("OK")){
                iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();




                // Getting Caching directory 
                File cacheDirectory = getBaseContext().getCacheDir();
                cacheDirectory.delete();
                // Temporary file to store the downloaded image 
                File tmpFile = new File(cacheDirectory.getPath() + "/wpta_"+position+".png");               

                // The FileOutputStream to the temporary file
                FileOutputStream fOutStream = new FileOutputStream(tmpFile);

                // Creating a bitmap from the downloaded inputstream
                Bitmap b = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(iStream);             

                // Writing the bitmap to the temporary file as png file
                b.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG,100, fOutStream);              

                // Flush the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.flush();

                //Close the FileOutputStream
                fOutStream.close();             

                // Create a hashmap object to store image path and its position in the listview


                // Storing the path to the temporary image file
                hmBitmap.put("img",tmpFile.getPath());

                // Storing the position of the image in the listview
                hmBitmap.put("position",position);              

                // Returning the HashMap object containing the image path and position
                return hmBitmap;


               }else{
                    Log.i("nope", "nb");
                    String uriStr = "android.resource://" + "com.lars" + "/" + R.drawable.ic_launcher;
                    hmBitmap.put("img", uriStr);


                    hmBitmap.put("position",position);
                    return hmBitmap;
                }

            }catch (Exception e) {              
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String, Object> result) {
            // Getting the path to the downloaded image

            String path = (String) result.get("img");           

            // Getting the position of the downloaded image
            int position = (Integer) result.get("position");

            // Getting adapter of the listview

            adapter = (SimpleAdapter ) list.getAdapter();

            // Getting the hashmap object at the specified position of the listview
            HashMap<String, Object> hm = (HashMap<String, Object>) adapter.getItem(position);   

            // Overwriting the existing path in the adapter 
            hm.put("img",path);


            // Noticing listview about the dataset changes
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Void... values) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
             publishProgress();

             adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
             Log.i("Image Task", "Update");

            super.onProgressUpdate(values);
        }
    }

    private OnItemClickListener onAnswerClicked = new OnItemClickListener() {

        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            HashMap<String, String> o = (HashMap<String, String>) parent.getItemAtPosition(position);

            Bundle extra = new Bundle();
            Intent i = new Intent("com.lars.productdescription");
            extra.putString("id", o.get("id"));
            i.putExtras(extra);
            startActivity(i);
        }

    };

    private OnScrollListener onAnswersScrolled = new OnScrollListener() {


        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int first, int visibleitems, int totalitemcount) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            int lastInScreen = first + visibleitems;  
            if(lastInScreen == totalitemcount){
            if(kf == 0){
                Log.i("onScroll", ""  + c);
                Log.i("kf", "0");
                String filfinal = keuze.replace(" ", "thisisaspace");
                String strUrl = "http://www.lars.nl/getName.php?name=" + filfinal + "&page=" + c ;
                DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                    downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
                    c = c + o;
                    Log.i("After Scroll", "" + c);
            }else{
                Log.i("onScroll", "" + c);
                Log.i("kf", "1");
                 String strUrl = "http://www.lars.nl/get.php?id=" + filter + "&page=" + c ;
                    DownloadTask downloadTask = new DownloadTask();
                        downloadTask.execute(strUrl);
                        c = c + o;
                        Log.i("After Scroll", "" + c);
            }
            }
        }

        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView view, int scrollstate) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    };

    }
```

Comment: Just a side note: Personally, I prefer using Gson over the 'standard' json classes. Google will help you find [a quick introduction like this one](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html).

Comment: Lot of code!! can you summarize what exact problem you are facing?

Comment: The problem is it doesnt add items to the current listview and adding a footer doesnt work. I wanna get JSON data into a listview with images and when i scroll down i want to load more items and add them to the current listview

Comment: whats the classcastexception?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd like to introduce you to [CWAC-ENDLESS](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless) by non other than the brilliant mark murphy (commonsware).  Not only is it a fine example of the power of putting an adapter inside another adapter, it handles all the background tasks for you as well as scrolling so that your data list may be added to very easily by following the [demo](https://github.com/commonsguy/cwac-endless/tree/master/demo)

I sincerely hope this helps you as much as its helped me.